# Create multiple Timeout objects on NodeJS using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, scalability

Using node.js, how scalable would it be to call `setInterval` multiple times?
I would like to create a job system in which periodic jobs would need to be executed at different intervals and my current solution is to create a [Timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) (by calling `setInterval`) for every new job.

Currently, I'm setting my callback functions as async calls.

I'm trying to understand the best scalable & performant practice to maintain a growing number of Timeouts objects in a node.js application in order to avoid of future memory and performance issues.

Comment: I would suggest using Promises. Edit: Ah, and setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Comment: @atmin can you elaborate please?

Comment: Your question is vague and it's hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Noob maintain and execute a growing number of periodical jobs on a nodejs application

Answer (score 0):

Ouh, an elaboration is hard, since I don't know exactly, would should be done.

Ok, let me have a try (maybe I'm in luck). Generally You could think of something like:

```
function Job {
    function taskA() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve('result A');
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
    function taskB(arg) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve('result B of ' + arg);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
    // would allow this chain:
    this.work = () => {
        taskA()
            .then(resA => taskB(resA))
            .then(resB => console.log(resB));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't need a chain of calls. I'm trying to understand how to maintain multiple Timeouts to periodically execute jobs.

Comment: Ok, maybe You could call taskA again, after it has been resolved. So it would be a chain of the very same Promise. That was my thought. I would not be afraid of stackoverflows, but I'm not really sure. After all it would work as an interval, but was more scalable.